# Relation between conditional expectation and CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let X be a nonnegative random variable. We know:

1. $F_X(1)=0.7, F_X(3)=0.9$
2. $E(X-1)_+=5.5, E(X-3)_+=5$

Find $E(X|X \in (1,3])$.

I know that
$EX = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))dx$
and I have to use that, but I don't have a clue how. It would be nice when $E(X|X \in (1,3])=E(X-1)_+-E(X-3)_+$ but it isn't true.

Comment: $E(X \mid (1, 3]) = E(X \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in (1,3]\}}) / P(X \in (1, 3]),$ the denominator is $F_X(3) - F_X(1)$ and the numerator is $X \mathbf{1}_{\{X > 1\}} - X \mathbf{1}_{\{X > 3\}}$ Notice that $E(X-a)_+ = E((X-a)\mathbf{1}_{\{X > a\}})$ for every $a.$

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, from that I have already what I wanted to. One thing more. We got the following formula as a hint:
$g(d_1) = g(d_2) - (d_2-d_1)(1-F(d_2)) - [E(X|X\in(d_1,d_2]) - d_1](F(d_2)-F(d_1))$

When I used your clue in $E(X|X\in (d_1,d_2])$, then after few modifications I have got the above formula, but I am wondering about what is the matter of that pattern. Has someone seen that already or something?